# Use inline query or join to get data from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, query-optimization

Using SQL server 2008 R2
which one is better (quicker, less intermediate tables, less memory usage) and the usual practice?

```
SELECT staff.id, staff.name, details.address, salary.hourly_rate, 
manager.name, boss.name
FROM STAFF_TABLE staff
LEFT JOIN STAFF_DETAILS_TABLE details on staff.id = details.id
LEFT JOIN STAFF_SALARY_TABLE salary on staff.id = salary.id
LEFT JOIN STAFF_TABLE manager on staff.manager_id = manager.id
LEFT JOIN STAFF_TABLE boss on staff.boss_id = boss.id
```

or

```
SELECT staff.id, staff.name, 
(SELECT address FROM STAFF_DETAILS_TABLE  id = staff.id) [address], 
(SELECT hourly_rate FROM STAFF_SALARY_TABLE WHERE id = staff.id) [hourly_rate], 
(SELECT name FROM STAFF_TABLE WHERE id = staff.manager_id) [manager_name], 
(SELECT name FROM STAFF_TABLE WHERE id = staff.boss_id) [boss_name]
FROM STAFF_TABLE staff
```

Thank you!

Comment: Generally the query optimiser will cut through both of these to give the same query execution plan. Check the plan and see if they are the same, if so there is NO performance differance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have indexes on all the appropriate ids in all the tables, the queries should generate the same execution plan.  One slight difference is that the optimizer might treat the in-line queries differently, because they must return only one row (else it generates an error).

I much prefer to keep all table references in the `from` clause, where possible.  I find that it makes it easier to maintain queries -- all the table references are in one place.  So, I much prefer the format with the explicit `joins`.

Answer (score 2):

The only real way to get an answer to that is to time it and examine the execution plans of the various queries.  I believe that SQL Server will try to optimize the query so there may be very little difference in the time.  The version with the JOIN is much more readable and would be my preference if there isn't a huge difference in the performance.